# Vue.js SPA Facebook auth

Tags: oauth, vue.js

I'm making my simple social network with Node.JS, Hapi and Vue. I want to have Facebook login. As Fcebook Auth can't be done in SPA I came up with the following method.

1. Add login button to SPA. This is link to server route which will redirect request to Facebook
2. User will log in with facebook
3. Server will return simple HTML page which will include JWT, and store JWT in browser's session store
4. that simple page will than redirect browser to SPA

Is there better way to do it? Should I somehow place JWT in SPA index.html page??

Comment: Yes, you could do that. I'd suggest a different approach, though - open up a popup window, do it there, and pass the data back to the parent window once the login is completed.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that yes you should store it on the database that way you don't have to make so many requests to facebook. Then what you would do is authenticate the user by their api-token that has been generated by your server. When they have to have their permissions checked you won't have to hit the facebook api every time you check permissions. You will only have to hit the api when it's important.

You could also store it as a global variable and check for it that way, but either way I think you would have to store it somewhere to reference it incase the user exits the site because then they would lose their variable and you would have to hit the fb api again.

What you could also do is store it in localStorage, or sessionStorage, but it's better to have a framework that handles that for you.

like [this one!](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hapi-auth-jwt2)